# Foreach glob loop not going through all files in PHP

Tags: php, database, foreach

I'm currently setting up a search engine and has been experiencing some weird stuff with this loop, and it seams like it doesn't go through all the 200 000 files.

I can see the file on the server, but when I search for it, it doesn't show up. Other searches, it works just fine.

The folders it's searching through have another layer of folders, and all the files are only stored on the last layer of folders. so I'm searching like this:

```
glob('database/*/*/*.txt')
```

Here is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])){
    $search = $_GET['q'];
}else{die;}

$files = array();

foreach (glob('database/*/*/*.txt', GLOB_NOCHECK) as $path) {
    $title = basename($path, ".txt").PHP_EOL;
    if(strripos($title,$search) != false){
        array_push( $files, $path );
        echo $title . '<br>';
        echo $path . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Error log shows nothing and access log gives 200 response.

Is it any other ways to search files in folders? or is it something that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Please share the sample result of `print_r(glob('database/*/*/*.txt', GLOB_NOCHECK));` and `print_r($search);`.

Comment: @SahilGulati `print_r(glob('database/*/*/*.txt', GLOB_NOCHECK));` returns 176 000 files which is all files. (checked terminal: "find . -type f | wc -l" ). It also includes the word I'm searching for when CTRL+F. 
`print_r($search);` returns the word.

Comment: I want to get a sample of files list and word you are looking for, So that i can better help you out.

Comment: Does the code iterate the foreach-loop? Try putting var_dump($title) inside of the loop and after the $title = ....

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld `var_dump($title)` returns all the files 180 752 'string(xx) "File Title"'. The database crawls meaning that it stores more and more data by itself.

Comment: So I guess something is wrong around this code: `if(strripos($title,$search) != false){` I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it - all your titles are fetched into the foreach-loop, but they are not included in the `array $files`. Therefore it would make sense to dig into the if statement:

```
if(strripos($title,$search) != false){
```

The manual from php.net states:

> Warning This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Because you should use === to check equal state, you should use !== (and not !=) to state not equal. Therefore the first thing I would test would be:

```
if(strripos($title,$search) !== false){
```

If it's still the same issue I would try to remove `PHP_EOL` from the line:

```
 $title = basename($path, ".txt").PHP_EOL;
```

and have it like this instead:

```
 $title = basename($path, ".txt");
```

I'm not sure why you're are using `PHP_EOL` here, but I don't think it is necessary? (not sure though - someone - tell me if I'm wrong).

So the code that would be left is this:

```
foreach (glob('database/*/*/*.txt', GLOB_NOCHECK) as $path) {
    $title = basename($path, ".txt");
    if(strripos($title,$search) !== false){
        array_push( $files, $path );
        echo $title . '<br>';
        echo $path . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. Should have been `if(strripos($title,$search) !== false){` instead of `if(strripos($title,$search) != false){` Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm glad to be of some help :-)